# React comment section not updating properly after submission. Anyone got tips? (screenshots provided)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My issue is that when I submit a comment and the state gets updated, the chat does not update properly. Here's a screenshot of how it looks before commenting and after. I'm not entirely sure why the dots appear, as from my understanding, it should update with the comments, and there are no empty comments in the database.

Edit: Just added the chat return!

[image: before:]

[image: after:]

Here's my code for the chat component:

```
const Chat = () => {
const {loggedIn, setLoggedIn} = useContext(LoginContext) 
const {loginUsername, setLoginUsername} = 
useContext(UsernameContext)
const {tickerValue, setTickerValue} = useContext(TickerValue)
console.log('LOGIN USERNAME:' + loginUsername)
const history = useHistory()
///const value = history.location.state
const searchValue = tickerValue.toUpperCase()
const classes = styles()
const [comments, setComments] = useState([])
const commentSection = []

useEffect(() => {
    if (messageDiv) {
        messageDiv.scrollIntoView(false)
    }
    if (searchValue.length > 0) {
        console.log('SEARCHVALUE ' + searchValue)
        console.log('checking comments')
        Axios.get('https://stockliner.herokuapp.com/comment_sections/' + searchValue)
        .then((res) => {
            const data = res.data
            //console.log(data)
            commentSection.push(data)
           
            setComments(data)
        })
    }
},[])


const postComment = () => {
    const content = document.getElementById('commentPost').value
    console.log(content)
    if (loginUsername.length > 0) {
        Axios.post("https://stockliner.herokuapp.com/add_comment", {
            stock_name: searchValue,
            username: loginUsername,
            content:  content
        })
        .then((res) => {
            Axios.get('https://stockliner.herokuapp.com/comment_sections/' + searchValue)
            .then((data) => {
                const comm = res.data
                setComments(comm)
                console.log(comments)
                ///window.location.reload()
            })
            console.log(res)
        })
    } else {
        alert('YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN')
    }
}
return(
    <div>
        <Card elevation={6} className={classes.commentCard}>
            <CardHeader align="left" title={searchValue + "'s Comments"}/>
            <Divider className={classes.titleDiv}/>
            <div className={classes.textPanel} id="messageDiv">
                {comments ? 
                    Object.keys(comments).map((key) => {
                        return(
                            <div className={classes.row}>
                                <Paper variant="outlined" className={classes.paperDiv}>
                                    <Typography className={classes.username}variant="body">{comments[key].username}: </Typography>
                                    <Typography className={classes.content}variant="body">{comments[key].content}</Typography>
                                </Paper>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                    : <p>no comments</p>
                }
            </div>
            <Divider className={classes.postDiv}/>
                {loggedIn? 
                    <div className={classes.titleDiv}>
                        <TextField variant="outlined" 
                        label="Comment" size="small" 
                        id="commentPost"/>
                        <Button variant="outlined" className= 
                   {classes.button} onClick= 
                    {postComment}>Post</Button>
                    </div>
                    :
                    <div className={classes.postDiv}>
                        <TextField variant="outlined" disabled 
                        label="Login required" size="small"/>
                        <Button variant="outlined" className= 
                     {classes.button} disabled>Post</Button>
                    </div>
                }
            </Card>
    </div>
)


}

export default Chat
```

Comment: What is `commentSection`? Should you be pushing into it? Other than this, how are you rendering your `comments` state? Can you share your entire chat component so we may see everything it does?

Comment: commentSection is an array variable that I was using before and forgot to remove. I just did it but the error persists! I added the rest of my code in the post

Comment: Component code is still incomplete, and the little bit you added seems like it should go with *some* user registration component, not a comment posting component.

Comment: You are right. Momentary lapse of judgement haha! The updated version contains the whole component function.

Comment: You've written your JSX a little "odd" but I don't immediately see any overt issues. Inside `postComment` in the second request to fetch the comments, what is this response? Does it contain the new comments you expect to see?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty new to this but I know my code could be much cleaner. The response seems adequate, it mentions that one row was affected and the comment does show up in the database after a mysql workbench refresh

Comment: Well, I was asking more that you are seeing the correct comments data come back in the response in the `postComment` handler. If you are, can you validate that your state is updated with the correct new data? Basically just follow the trail of response data -> state updated -> JSX renders new data.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that. The console logs all comments including the newest one after posting. I think the issue is with the return somehow, but I am not sure how my code could be causing that tbh

Comment: So, the `comments` state is correctly updated, but `Object.keys(comments)` isn't rendering it? This doesn't make a lot of sense. Try adding a React key to the row div, something like a comment id if it exists. This is about the only thing I see missing. If this isn't it then try making a *running* codesandbox with mocked state from response data and see if you can replicated the issue for us to examine.

Answer (score 0):

in useEffect hook there is a list of variables whoose state change you follow and your list is empty, try adding variable there

Comment: you mean commentSection? I'm not entirely sure how that would be causing the problem to be honest. What exactly do you mean by 'adding a variable there'? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Turns out on the second .then after the postComment function, I was updating my state with setComments(res.data) where it should have been setComment(data.data) because "res" was the response of the first .then and "data" was for the second. Dumb mistake but it took me two days to fix!